# call was rejected by callee

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2008

My application was working fine on my win 7 64 bit machine.

I tried to run the winforms visual studio 2008 .NET C# application on a different win 7 64 bit machine and now I am getting this error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010001): Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.get_Worksheets()
   at EmailSalesVolumeSolution.WorkBook.OpenWorkBook() in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\WorkBook.cs:line 40
   at EmailSalesVolumeSolution.WorkBook.CreateFiles(String column, Boolean isTest) in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\WorkBook.cs:line 144
   at EmailSalesVolumeSolution.Form1.InitializeWorkBook(String filename) in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\Form1.cs:line 108
   at EmailSalesVolumeSolution.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\EmailSalesVolumeSolution\Form1.cs:line 86
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
EmailSalesVolumeSolution
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/agordon/Desktop/Debug/EmailSalesVolumeSolution.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5460 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5462 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
GenericParsing
    Assembly Version: 1.1.3.20921
    Win32 Version: 1.1.3.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/agordon/Desktop/Debug/GenericParsing.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.0.4756.1000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

here's a screenshot:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue?

**what does the error mean?**

Comment: I would guess that the "RPC" error is coming from the interop assembly. Have you checked that Excel is installed on the other machine? And that it's the same version as on yours?

Comment: @David do you have any idea whether this might be applicable? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant thank you very much for your feedback. i just dont understand why it works on other machines and not this one. excel is fully functional here!

Comment: @HansPassant how would i go about ignoring or investigating this error/

Comment: @HansPassant i was wondering if would kingly guide me on this :)

Comment: @HansPassant thank you again for yoru help, i was just wondering if you could point me into the right direction

Comment: @hanspassant were you just kidding about your comment?

Comment: @David im sorry to bug you, but i was wondering if you could please point me into the right directino on this. what should i be exploring to solve this?

Comment: The link you supplied points at threading issues, as Hans Passant -- who is much more knowledgeable than I -- also suggested.  That's where I would start looking.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick and dirty solution, add a thread.sleep after you create the excel object.

Something like this:

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when `Microsoft Office` applied new updates which required some confirmations.

So, I had to manually open `Microsoft Excel`, click "OK", and the error is gone.