# how to properly GetTypeFromProgID for visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, interop, envdte

I am following the instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.80).aspx

for .net 3.5 visual studio 2008 to fix this issue:

[call was rejected by callee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358944/call-was-rejected-by-callee)

for this line of code:

```
t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.8.0",
              true);
```

I am getting this error:

> COMException was unhandled: Invalid class string (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))

Does anyone know what this means, and what am I doing wrong?

thank you so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't match the tag you used.  VS2008 is Visual Studio version 9.0.  So the proper progid is `VisualStudio.DTE.9.0`.  The full list of version numbers:

- VS2002 : 7.0
- VS2003 : 7.1
- VS2005 : 8.0
- VS2008 : 9.0
- VS2010 : 10.0
- VS2012 : 11.0
- VS2013 : 12.0

You can also use the `VisualStudio.DTE` progid.  You'll get whatever version of VS was installed last.  A bit random.

Comment: thank you hans, so i should be referencing visual studio development environment 9.0?

Comment: No, you should use "VisualStudio.DTE.9.0"

Comment: thanks so much! i meant when i reference the com object shoudl be "visual studio development environment 9.0" ??

Comment: just using VisualStudio.DTE, does not work. i just downloaded VS 2008 express and 9.0 did not work!

Comment: Sigh, of course it doesn't.  Express is the free VS edition, it doesn't support anything like add-ins and the extensibility interfaces.

Comment: thank you. so in this case i cannot run my program at all on a computer that does not have visual studio installed?

Comment: Erm, it will surely run on my computer.  Like it did for the guy that posted the web page.  My machine has th retail edition of Visual Studio installed.  I paid the license fee for a crucial tool I use every day to get my job done.  If you're trying to make money from nothing then you usually end up with nothing.  A principle never well understood in your neck of the woods?

Comment: i dont understand why the user should be forced to pay for a development tool that they won't even use

Comment: That comment is five thousand miles away from anything that would make sense I my neck of the woods.  Why are you not hacking Linux + Mono?  No strings attached, it is all free.

Comment: you know the reason i have to pay for the license of VS comes down to the fact that they have a bug in it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.80).aspx  - if it were not for this bug, i would not need to get an extra full version of VS